# How can I get HTML element coordinates?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was wondering if there is a way to get the coordinates of an HTML element in an HTML page without opening the page in the browser.
I'm using python and I saw that you can pull some requests to get the HTML page and after that, you can search inside it using modules like `bs4` but I didn't find a way to get the element coordinates, is that possible? *(for element coordinates I mean the `x pos` and `y pos` of the element when the page is loaded by the broswer)*

Let us say that I want to get the HTML text of [this page](https://www.nike.com)
and i have wrote this

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get("https://www.nike.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

element = soup.find('p',{'class':"vVtA7wL6 headline-sm-base text-color-primary-dark"})

print(element.coords) # exists/can I create in some way a module that returns the coords?
```

Is there a way to find the `element.coords` when the element is displayed in the browser?

Comment: What is expected results? What do you want to archive?

Comment: It would need to render the entire page offscreen and then access the DOM. It is not sufficient to download only the html file, it would also need CSS, Javascript, images, etc. Maybe use PythonWebKit or another library which gives access to the WebKit API for example.

Comment: I want to get the element coords for be able to click it or screenshot it, i want to be able to interact with it without using selenium

Comment: ok, i'm goonna see it thanks @tmlen

Comment: It's not possible to do this purely from html.  X,Y coordinates will depend heavily on the device screen resolution.

Comment: @Mat.C Are you trying to just take screenshot of the page without using selenium?

Comment: No, i'm trying to fully interact with the broswer without using selenium

Answer (score 2):

In general not possible, because coordinates depend on how exactly given browser renders it.

But you can open some browser in python, and run a javascript which retrieves coordinates and returns it to python. We will use pywebview as a browser (requires `pip3 install pywebview`).

Open browser window, use JavaScript to examine HTML element, return values, and close browser window. Note the values will depend on window size.

```
import webview
from threading import Thread


def thread_fun():
  while webview.evaluate_js('document.readyState') != "complete":
    # wait for page to load
    time.sleep(0.5)

  # ask for a bounding rect
  bounding_rect = webview.evaluate_js('''
    document.querySelector("img.central-featured-logo").getBoundingClientRect()
  ''');  
  webview.destroy_window()

  print(bounding_rect)


thread = Thread(target=thread_fun)
thread.start()

webview.create_window(title="a title", url="http://wikipedia.org", width=500, height=700)

thread.join()
```

Result: `{'x': 150, 'y': 176, 'width': 200, 'height': 183, 'top': 176, 'right': 350, 'bottom': 359, 'left': 150}`

`webview.create_window` must be called in main thread, it blocks it until window is destroyed.

For details on the webview package see https://pywebview.flowrl.com/